# MacOS - Combine multiple text files into one spreadsheet with one file per a column?

Tags: csv, text, merge, terminal

Using MacOS terminal, is there away to take a directory of text files and have them all combined into one spreadsheet (either CSV or Numbers format) so:

- Every file is in a separate column
- Every line of the txt file is in a separate row.
- The files are placed in the spreadsheet in alphabetical order (using the first letter of file name of the text file).

Example 1: here is how my text files look before combining:
[image: Example of text files]

Example 2: here is how my text files should look in a spreadsheet after combining:
[image]

(These examples are a partial extract. I actually have 100s of files to combine).

---

**Steps I have tried:**

1. I searched Stack Overflow for an answer, but all the other questions about this task use Python or Panda. I would prefer a solution that could be done directly from MacOS terminal without needing to install packages like Python or Panda.
2. From researching, I believe the `paste` command could be used:

   `paste -d '\t' *.txt > ^0-merged.csv`

However, when I try this, it produces the following error message: `paste: Too many open files`. It also produces a CSV file that is completely blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is part of MacOS.

Given:

```
head -n 3 *.txt
==> GOOD THINGS IN LIFE.txt <==
Art
Fun
Hugs

==> IN THE BACKYARD.txt <==
Hose
Tree
Soil

==> KITCHEN CUPBOARD ESSENTIALS.txt <==
Tea
Rice
Milk

==> KNITTING STITCHES.txt <==
Rib
Dip
Seed

# and the rest of your lines in each case...
```

You can do:

```
ruby -e '
a=[]
ARGV.sort.each{|fn|
    a<<[fn]+File.open(fn).read.split(/\R/)
}
a.transpose.each{|sa|
    puts sa.join(",")
}
' *.txt
```

Prints:

```
GOOD THINGS IN LIFE.txt,IN THE BACKYARD.txt,KITCHEN CUPBOARD ESSENTIALS.txt,KNITTING STITCHES.txt
Art,Hose,Tea,Rib
Fun,Tree,Rice,Dip
Hugs,Soil,Milk,Seed
Earth,Fence,Salt,Tile
Honor,Porch,Pesto,Linen
Space,Patio,Flour,Cable
Sport,Grass,Honey,Wicker
Intelligence,Wading Pool,Baking Powder,Knotted Boxes
Innovation,Welcome Mat,Vegetable Oil,Chinese Wave
Confidence,Back Stoop,Tomato Paste,Checkerboard
Good Deeds,Fruit Tree,Black Pepper,Herringbone
Creativity,Downspout,Baking Soda,Stockinette
Education,Birdbath,Ketchup,Garter
Kindness,Terrace,Surer,Waffle
Integrity,Planter,Sugar,Puri Ridge
Faith,Carport,Coffee,Netted
Friends,Flowerbed,Cinnamon,Elongated
Respect,Shovel,Cheese,Farrow Rib
People,Hedges,Bread,Plaited
Yourself,Rocks,Olive Oil,Clamshell
Happiness,Lawnmower,Crackers,Bamboo
Heart,Hot Tub,Pasta,English Rib
Religion,Garden,Scissors,Basket
Wisdom,Stoop,Garlic,Raspberry
```

If you want a 'proper' csv with quoted fields that works better with Excel, you can use the CSV module included with Ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
a=[]
ARGV.sort.each{|fn|
    a<<[fn]+File.open(fn).read.split(/\R/)
}
a=a.transpose
puts CSV.generate(**{headers:true, quote_empty:true, force_quotes:true}){|csv|
    csv<<a[0]
    a[1..].each{|row|
        csv<<row
    }
}
' *.txt
```

Prints:

```
"GOOD THINGS IN LIFE.txt","IN THE BACKYARD.txt","KITCHEN CUPBOARD ESSENTIALS.txt","KNITTING STITCHES.txt"
"Art","Hose","Tea","Rib"
"Fun","Tree","Rice","Dip"
"Hugs","Soil","Milk","Seed"
"Earth","Fence","Salt","Tile"
"Honor","Porch","Pesto","Linen"
"Space","Patio","Flour","Cable"
"Sport","Grass","Honey","Wicker"
"Intelligence","Wading Pool","Baking Powder","Knotted Boxes"
"Innovation","Welcome Mat","Vegetable Oil","Chinese Wave"
"Confidence","Back Stoop","Tomato Paste","Checkerboard"
"Good Deeds","Fruit Tree","Black Pepper","Herringbone"
"Creativity","Downspout","Baking Soda","Stockinette"
"Education","Birdbath","Ketchup","Garter"
"Kindness","Terrace","Surer","Waffle"
"Integrity","Planter","Sugar","Puri Ridge"
"Faith","Carport","Coffee","Netted"
"Friends","Flowerbed","Cinnamon","Elongated"
"Respect","Shovel","Cheese","Farrow Rib"
"People","Hedges","Bread","Plaited"
"Yourself","Rocks","Olive Oil","Clamshell"
"Happiness","Lawnmower","Crackers","Bamboo"
"Heart","Hot Tub","Pasta","English Rib"
"Religion","Garden","Scissors","Basket"
"Wisdom","Stoop","Garlic","Raspberry"
```

---

Comments:

> It also puts the file name at the top of every column. Is there any
> way to omit the file name? Also, it seems to treat Uppercase A-Z and
> lowercase a-z as separate (e.g. so file names with A-Z will come first
> and then file names with a-z) Thanks!

If you have files of different length, you can pad the end of the shorter files so that you still have a proper matrix to transpose:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
a=[]
ARGV.sort_by{|s| s.downcase}.each{|fn|
    a<<File.open(fn).read.split(/\R/)
}
max_length=a.max_by{|sa| sa.length}.length
a.each.with_index{|sa,i| 
    if sa.length<max_length then a[i].concat [""]*(max_length-sa.length) end }
a=a.transpose
puts CSV.generate(**{headers:true, quote_empty:true, force_quotes:true}){|csv|
    csv<<a[0]
    a[1..].each{|row|
        csv<<row
    }
}
' *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! When I try this, it produces this error in the terminal ‑-e:6:in `transpose': element size differs (36 should be 27) (IndexError)
 from -e:6:in `<main>' ` Any ideas?

Comment: This is because your files differ in size where your example has all the same sizes. You can make them all the same length (which is trivial in Ruby) but question is: Which rows are then to be considered blank? All at the end?

Comment: @dwag Thanks, that works! But is there anyway to output into a file, rather than display in the terminal. It also puts the file name at the top of every column. Is there any way to omit the file name? Also, it seems to treat Uppercase A-Z and lowercase a-z as separate (e.g. so file names with A-Z will come first and then file names with a-z) Thanks!

Comment: To output to a file, simply redirect the output in zsh / Bash with `> output_file` right after the `*.txt` in this case. Other items fixed in last version.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through appending each file.

```
touch merged.csv
for f in *.txt; do paste -d '\t' $f merged.csv > temp; cp temp merged.csv; done; rm temp
```

You have to create the file first as the paste will fail if it can't find the file.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205642/combining-large-amount-of-files

Adding a new idea for files with spaces in.

```
#!/bin/bash
touch merged.csv

# save and change IFS
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
 
# read all file name into an array
fileArray=($(find ./ -name "*.txt" | sort))
 
# restore it
IFS=$OLDIFS
 
# get length of an array
tLen=${#fileArray[@]}
 
# use for loop read all filenames
for (( i=0; i<${tLen}; i++ ));
do
  paste -d '\t' "${fileArray[$i]}" merged.csv > temp; 
  cp temp merged.csv; 
done
rm temp
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Except, is there any way to have it, so it places the text files in column by alphabetical order of the file names (Sorry, I forgot to put the alphabetical part in my question. I am so used to having all my files displayed in alphabetical order in a folder that I forgot to mention it!)

Comment: If you don't have spaces in the filenames, then this should work 
```for f in `ls *.txt | sort`; do paste -d '\t' $f merged.csv > temp; cp temp merged.csv; done; rm temp```

Comment: Thanks! My files actually do have spaces in the file names. Any work around for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated it with a new idea. Just put that in a script and run.

Comment: The potential problem here is if files are of different length the columns will not be filled to match the longer columns.

Comment: @nowait That works, accept it comes in reverse file name order (e.g. from z-A) Is there anyway to flip it around so it goes A-Z? Also, it seems to treat Uppercase A-Z and lowercase a-z as separate (e.g. so file names with A-Z will come first and then file names with a-z). It also prints out this error message, I am not sure if that is causing the order to be wrong: `rm temp
zsh: command not found: #
zsh: command not found: #
zsh: command not found: #
zsh: command not found: #
zsh: command not found: #
paste: : No such file or directory`

Comment: change `fileArray=($(find ./ -name "*.txt" | sort))` to `fileArray=($(find ./ -name "*.txt" | sort -r))` will reverse the order. And if you add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of the script it will tell it which shell to use.